# Best practices for HTML and divs

Tags: css, html

I would like to know the best way of using HTML5 and `div` tags together. I have posted my html below.
I am using the `article` tag then I have sections which I am sure are correct, but I am using grids as well, so where should I put the **grid** `div`?
Is my method the best way of doing it?

```
<article>
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <section>
      <div class="grid-4-col">
        <h1>Welcome Back</h1>
       <p>It has been a while. What have you been up to lately?</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="grid-4-col">
    <h1>Welcome Back</h1>
    <p>It has been a while. What have you been up to lately?</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="grid-4-col">
    <h1>Welcome Back</h1>
    <p>It has been a while. What have you been up to lately?</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="grid-4-col grid-last">
    <h3>Chicago</h3>
    <h5 hidden>City in Illinois</h5>
    <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago, the third most populous city in the United States">
    <ul>
      <li>234 square miles</li>
      <li>2.715 million residents</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: FYI...it appears you have an end div tag between your end section and article.

Comment: I just use divs as often as possible: no <p> no <li> no <ul> no <section> no <article> because in the end, you can do without all these. No sure it the "best" practice but it's my practice and it works; keeps the code simple and clean.

Answer (score 2):

According to HTML5Doctor, the way you've gone about it is fine. You're effectively using the divs as wrappers and that's permitted.

Source: http://html5doctor.com/you-can-still-use-div/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a grid system, and a section element sections off content, you want the section to be inside the grid, which is defined by the div. So put the section element inside the div. Otherwise, your grid is relative to the section and not the whole page and grid system.